# I couldn't handle to write a histogram

Tags: c, histogram

My aim is to generate a histogram for repeated numbers. The code works well until the frequency is bigger than 2.

I think I know what is wrong with the code (line 9) but I cannot find an algorithm to solve it. The problem that I have is when it writes the histogram, it separates and then gathers it again.

My Input:

```
5
5 6 6 6 7
```

Output:

```
6:2 6:2 6:3
```

but the output I need is

```
6:3
```

I kind of see the problem but I couldn't solve it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int array[25];
    int i, j, num, count = 1;

    scanf("%d", &num);

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < i ; j++) {
            if (array [i] == array[j]) {
                count++;
                printf("%d:%d ", array[i], count);
              }
        }
        array [i] = array[j];

        count = 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Atleast first read the input complete then search for the histogram.

Comment: You should first read all input values to your array, then process the numbers to create the histogram. One possible algorithm is to sort the data and count the number of subsequent equal numbers.

Comment: What is the range of the numbers? If it is limited, you can create a second array with index 0 to n, for storing the number of occurrences of values between 0 to n. If you for example encounter a 5, you would do `occurrences[5]++`.

Comment: _" the output I need is `6:3`"_ : It is not clear to me what that means or why you expect that output?  What about the instances of 5 and 7 in your example?  Would you not expect `5:1 6:3 7:1`?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to count occurrences before all units have been accepted, which is not possible unless you maintain a separate counter for each value, which in turn is not practical if there is no restriction on the input value range or the range is large.

You need to have obtained *all* values before you can report any counts. Then for each value in the array, test if the value has occurred earlier, and if not, iterate the whole array to count occurrences:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    // Get number of values
    int num = 0 ;
    scanf("%d", &num);

    // Get all values
    int array[25];
    for( int i = 0; i < num; i++) 
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    // For each value in array...
    for( int i = 0; i < num ; i++) 
    {
        // Check value not already counted
        bool counted = false ;
        for( int j = 0; !counted && j < i; j++ )
        {
            counted = array[j] == array[i] ;
        }

        // If current value has not previously been counted...
        if( !counted )
        {
            // Count occurnaces
            int count = 0 ;
            for( int j = 0; j < num; j++ )
            {
                if( array[j] == array[i] )
                {
                    count++ ;
                }
            }

            // Report
            printf("%d:%d ", array[i], count);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For your example input, the result is:

```
5                                                                                                                                              
5 6 6 6 7                                                                                                                                      
5:1 6:3 7:1
```

It is possible to merge the two inner loops performing the `counted` and `count` evaluation:

```
    // Count occurrences of current value, 
    bool counted = false ;
    int count = 0 ;
    for( int j = 0; !counted && j < num; j++ )
    {
        if( array[j] == array[i] )
        {
            count++;

            // Discard count if value occurs earlier - already counted
            counted = j < i ;
        }
    }

    // If current value has not previously been counted...
    if( !counted )
    {
        // Report
        printf("%d:%d ", array[i], count);
    }
}
```